# How can I get HttpWebRequest to work with Netduino? It is giving me System.NotSupportedException

Tags: .net, http, frameworks, netduino

I'm trying to send an http POST request from my netduino, I've been on the netduino forum and there is conflicting reports of this being able to work, the exception occurs on the first line

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("example.com:8080");

            string postData = "temperature=" + tempSensor.Temperature;
            byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Debug.Print(response.StatusDescription);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `.Create(...)` method, either pass an instance of `Uri` or include protoctol, i.e. `http://example.com:8080`.